# Data binding the function on click with multiple parameters knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have searched the net and tried different approaches mentioned but the click function sometimes fires and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is my html code

```
                <input  type="radio"   data-bind="checked:a,checkedValue: 0, click: radio('dance','a')"  id="a_normal"  ><span class="OptionsTextProperties"> Normal </span>

                <input  type="radio"   data-bind="checked:a, checkedValue: 1 , click: radio('dance','a')"    id="a_abnormal" ><span class="OptionsTextProperties"> Abnormal </span>
```

Here is the function I am trying to call

```
 radio : function(key,key1)
     {
        console.log(key,key1);
        return;          
     },
```

Most of the time the above function fires but sometimes nothing happens when I click on the button. 
I have also used **bind** but that doesn't checks the radio button. Not sure what the problem is. I have also gone through many links here at stackoverflow. Maybe I am doing something wrong that I am not able to point out. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: It seems working in the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/gqaLcapv/1/ 
The click event fires always.

Comment: Hey Adrian, it does work most of the time... Even I tried it in a fiddle and it works well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`radio('dance','a')` has to return a function if you want to use it in a `click` data-bind.

More importantly: you shouldn't bind to the `click` event on a checkbox. You can check checkboxes using the keyboard; you'll miss those.

With knockout, it's better to `subscribe` to the data-bound value:

```js
var vm = {
  checked: ko.observable(false)
};

vm.checked.subscribe(function onCheck() {
    console.log("Click!");
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked">
  A checkbox
  </label>
```

If you *need* to bind via an event, I'd suggest to use the `change` event instead.

Comment: I need to do the binding on click since I am doing a lot of things at the backend when the radio button is clicked. I will try ur solution of using subscribe. Thank you